# Laravel authentication. How do I change the table 'users' to table 'staff'?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I am a beginner just using laravel for the first time. I adding authentication by

```
php artisan make:auth
```

and adding database by

```
php artisan migrate
```

But I already have an old database. I tried to change the database from table 'users' to table 'staff' according to the code below.

config/auth.php

```
    'providers' => [
    'staff' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
```

Found an error in Figure 1

Note I tried make a database table 'staff' like database table 'users'

Is there any file that I need to fix?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDrPy.png)

Comment: Are you change ` 'model' => App\User::class,` to ` 'model' => App\Staff::class,`?

Comment: Could you post your `App\Staff` model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `provider` array in `config/auth.php` should look like this.

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Staff::class,
    ]
]
```

Also, your `App\Staff` model should extend `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Staff extends Authenticatable
{

}
```